# Get data from the current time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `events` and I have two columns called `eventDate` and `time´

The point is, I insert the time manually and I would like to get the events today at the time that I have in my column `time`

EX:

`eventDate | time
26-10-2016 | 19:45`

I would like to get at 19:45 the event and after two hours dissapear

> I tried it but didn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE eventDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d-%m-%Y') AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

Forget the COUNT(*) I'm just using it to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE eventDate = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d-%m-%Y') AND time >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR),'%H:%i');
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked !! I'll accept your question in 3 minutes ! Thamks a lot !